# Terraform try/catch in a module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform v0.12.x, AWS provider

I'm trying to write a generic module that will either return an existing EBS snapshot of a passed-in EBS volume name, or take a snapshot of a passed-in EBS volume name. Either way it should return a snapshot id.

Here's the code to get an existing snapshot.

```
data "aws_ebs_snapshot" "snapshot" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.ebs_id]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "status"
    values = ["completed"]
  }
}

output "snapshot_id" {
  value       = data.aws_ebs_snapshot.snapshot.id
  description = "Jenkins master snapshot id"
}
```

and here's the code to take a snapshot.

```
data "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.ebs_id]
  }
}

// Take a snapshot of the green EBS resource
resource "aws_ebs_snapshot" "snapshot" {
  volume_id = data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs.id
}

output "snapshot_id" {
  value       = aws_ebs_snapshot.snapshot.id
  description = "Jenkins master snapshot id"
}
```

Is it possible to do this? If so how? I know I can separate them into 2 separate modules, but humor me.

```
# try/catch block is of course pseudo-code
try {
  # Get an existing snapshot id
  data "aws_ebs_snapshot" "snapshot" {
    most_recent = true
    filter {
      name   = "tag:Name"
      values = [var.ebs_name]
    }
    filter {
      name   = "status"
      values = ["completed"]
    }
  }

  output "snapshot_id" {
    value       = data.aws_ebs_snapshot.snapshot.id
    description = "Jenkins master snapshot id"
  }
}
catch() {
  # Get the volume id and take a snapshot
  data "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs" {
    most_recent = true
    filter {
      name   = "tag:Name"
      values = [var.ebs_id]
    }
  }
   
  // Take a snapshot of the green EBS resource
  resource "aws_ebs_snapshot" "snapshot" {
    volume_id = data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs.id
  }

  output "snapshot_id" {
    value       = aws_ebs_snapshot.snapshot.id
    description = "Jenkins master snapshot id"
  }
}
```

I know `try/catch` blocks are not used this way in Terraform, so how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: No, it isn't. HCL is a declarative language (like JSON or YAML), not a real programming language with constructs like exception handling.

Comment: I updated my question. Without using try/catch, how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Yes you can do this, and yes there is try/catch within Terraform, but the solution would not involve the `try` in this situation because it involves individual values, and not resources. Also, the code would look hacky for what you want, so a re-architecting is probably more ideal here.

Comment: @MattSchuchard please show me in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation you've described doesn't seem like one where it's necessary to make a dynamic decision based on the remote system, because you can tell entirely from the input variables whether the caller is specifying a snapshot id or a volume id:

```
variable "ebs_name" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

variable "ebs_id" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

data "aws_ebs_snapshot" "snapshot" {
  count = var.ebs_name != null ? 1 : 0

  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.ebs_name]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "status"
    values = ["completed"]
  }
}

data "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs" {
  count = var.ebs_id != null ? 1 : 0

  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.ebs_id]
  }
}
   
// Take a snapshot of the green EBS resource
resource "aws_ebs_snapshot" "snapshot" {
  count = var.ebs_id != null ? 1 : 0

  volume_id = data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs[count.index].id
}

output "snapshot_id" {
  # Return either the generated snapshot or the given
  # snapshot. If the caller specified both for some
  # reason then the generated snapshot takes priority.
  # This will produce an error if neither var.ebs_name
  # nor var.ebs_id is set, because the result will have
  # no elements.
  value = concat(
    aws_ebs_snapshot.snapshot[*].id,
    data.aws_ebs_snapshot.snapshot[*].id,
  )[0]
  description = "Jenkins master snapshot id"
}
```

For completeness in case someone else finds this answer in future I want to note that [the Module Composition guide](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html) suggests just directly writing out the straightforward read or create code for each case rather than making dynamic decisions in cases like these, but I showed the dynamic example above because you suggested (by reference to the possibility of using two modules to address this) that you'd already considered and decided against using a composition style.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the logic I was looking for. I'm just now learning the use of count.

Comment: This worked on the plan. However, on the subsequent `-destroy` I get `on ../module_snapshot/main.tf line 46, in output "snapshot_id":
  46:   )[0]
    |----------------
    | aws_ebs_snapshot.snapshot is empty tuple
    | data.aws_ebs_snapshot.snapshot is empty tuple

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.`

Comment: Ahh indeed, the output is assuming that at least one object will always exist, which wouldn't be true after a destroy. To be robust against that, the output expression could have a fallback for that situation where it returns `null` instead of failing.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance you might think that you could check if the snapshot exists via the data source, and then use something like `count` on the resource to create one if the data source didn't return anything. Unfortunately that's not how Terraform works because the data source will throw an error if it can't find a match, causing Terraform to exit.

See the official response from HashiCorp [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16380#issuecomment-517282340), when asked for the sort of capability you are looking for.

> The sort of dynamic decision-making that is being requested here runs
> counter to Terraform's design goals, since it makes the configuration
> a description of what might possibly be rather than what is.

In general this sort of thing is handled better via AWS CLI scripts, or something like a Python/boto3 script, instead of Terraform.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually trying to move away from AWS CLI scripts (via Jenkins pipeline) and moving to Terraform. I see this as a limitation.